# asp.net Grid best approach to binding

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I am using the followng code to bind to an ASP.NET  DataGrid. I have the following and it works but wondering if this is the best approach. Few things that concern me is that I did not nee to Open the connection and also I did not make use of the DataReader. Note that this is written in my code behind page.

```
             string strConn =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL1"].ConnectionString; 
             SqlDataSource DataSource1 = new SqlDataSource();  
             DataSource1.ConnectionString = strConn;
             DataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblTruck where LocId = @LocID ";     

             DataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("LocId", System.TypeCode.String, value));                 
             Grid1.DataSource = DataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty); 
             Grid1.Rebind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the DataSource control handles the internal logic of establishing a connection, reading off it, and parsing the return. this in itself is very handy, but causes problems if you need more control.

Stylistically, it is never ever a good idea to have SQL code hardcoded in your UI, though it is good you are using a parameter instead of concatenating.

overall there is no "best approach". based on factors like maintenance/change, code vulnerability, performance, reliability, display complexity, etc, your solution should be tailored to your problem.

Personally I don't like datasource controls, but they can be useful for grid work when you don't want to spend a lot of time configuring the grid.

SQLCommands are very very fast and optimal, but you have to write an maintain a lot of code to use them, and it can be somewhat brittle.

DataAdapters/DataReaders/DataTables/DataSets are somewhat easier to write an maintain than SQLCommands, but they can be cumbersom in memory, and often don't dispose correctly.

Linq/ENF both make writing and maintaining easy, but sometimes they leave you debugging issues with their own generated sql rather than your own, and are generally slower at execution (often by a not-insignifigant amount).

Hope that helps answer your question.

Comment: You mentioned - Stylistically, it is never ever a good idea to have SQL code hardcoded in your UI, though it is good you are using a parameter instead of concatenating. -- What I have written is in the code behind page. As such, is it OK. When you say UI are you referring to .aspx page vs .aspx.cs page?

Comment: Personally I woudl push it into a stored procedure depending on your DB backend, or into a config file so it can be adjusted without having to redeploy your codebase. I had an intern write an app once, and it worked great until another developer messed up a view that a grid was based on such that it duplicated values. I thought I should be able to just add DISTINCT to his stored procedure to patch it up until the view was repaired, but since he embedded his sql, I had to find his codebase, figure out how it all worked, recompile and redeploy. Databases change a lot over time.

Comment: @Fred Thomas- Thanks - What is your view on having SQL inside of the .aspx file itself. Do you think it is not a good practice as well? Is it better to have it in .cs file? (I know the best is to have it in a stored procedure but wanted to get you input on other types)

Comment: My recommendation is to 1) avoid putting them any file that gets compiled and 2) if possible store the file on a backend server so it cannot be easily retrieved if someone leverages an exploit on your server tier. if you have to have them at the app tier, then put them in a .cs file that is part of a dll project. that way if they change you can alter the dll project code, and just drop in a new copy of the dll. I've done that a lot over the years. of course my preference is to use stored procedures, but whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better try to progress your code to use of linq and other type of programming like entity frame work and etc.because they make your project faster and more reliable.and it  cause decrease coding.

Comment: Can you try an modify it to use entity framework as an example

Comment: this is the best reference of entity framework to learn.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx